# How to use primary key to many table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use one primary key to many table (foreign key) for e.g

Table 1:

```
 id --P K

1 
2
3
```

Table 2:

```
 id -- F K
```

Table 3:

```
 id -- F K
```

If I insert value to table 2 by using a stored procedure. it showing error

> constraint "FK_tbl_table2_tbl_table1_reg". The conflict occurred in database "BPMC", table "dbo.tbl_table1", column 'ID'.

where's error...thanks..

sorry i made error in sp datatype size....

Comment: what RDBMS you are working on ??? Does value `2` exist in tbl_Table1 and can you show definition of your stored procedure ??

Comment: Well, **show us the code** that you've written in your stored procedure! What values are you passing into the stored procedure?

Comment: I think the error should tell you enough... something needs to exist in `table1` before you can insert into `table2` because you cannot reference something from `table1` that does not exist

Comment: sorry i made error in sp variable size thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
table2 ID Column should be same datatype of table1
```

I could not add as a comment so add it in answer section.

Comment: i made error in sp variable size thanks....

Comment: @RadhamaniMuthusamy +1 Right on the spot !

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error from happening, make sure that the value you are inserting into a column that references another table exists in that table.  If the value does not exist in the primary table, insert to that table first before doing the insert on the second table.

<kbd>[Referential Integrity](http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/refintegrity.htm)</kbd>

Comment: i made error in sp variable size thanks....

Comment: @Happy We will be thankful if you can share your error and solution , Please so it may benefit others.

Comment: @Happy You mean `ForeignKey` variable size ?